# Find Planar Graph fromVertices and Faces

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, planar-graphs

**Could you find a 3-Regular Connected Planar Graph on $10$ vertices with $8$ faces? If so, explain carefully.**

> I don't know what does regular mean. I think that 3-connected graph on
>   10 vertices with 8 faces. From eulerian formula : $v + f - e = 2:$
>   $10+8-e=2 \Longrightarrow e=16$. And I use other proof *"A simple planar graph on v 
>   3 vertices has at most $\;3v- 6$ edges."* $\Longrightarrow 30-6=24$ edges at most. I
>   said that $24>16$, if so it can be.

Is it true or not?

*Thank you for your answers in advance.*

Comment: A $k$-regular graph is defined to be a graph where every vertex is of degree $k$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$3$-regular means that each vertex has degree $3$.  With $10$ vertices, how many edges would that make?

Comment: 3*10/2 = 15 edges. Is that mean that it must be 16 from eular formula but we found 15. It is impossible.

Comment: Its all good.  Already deleted that comment.  So, now you know the number of faces, edges, and vertices.  Check if it matches Euler's formula.